# After I compile my Java program, it says error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to double[]

Tags: java, compiler-errors, double

What can I do to fix this?

Here's part of the beginning of the code:

```
double fee;
double tuition;
double[] residence, total;
```

Here's the part where it's wrong:

```
total = tuition + fee;
```

> error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to double[]

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: What are these variables representing?  Why are you wanting an array (the `[]` thing)? (And where do you mention `fee`?)

Answer (score 1):

What you've done here is declared 4 variables: `fee` and `tuition` are of type `double`, while `residence` and `total` are of type `double[]` -- i.e. an *array* of elements of type `double`.

You're adding up `tuition` and `fee`, and what the compiler is expecting you to do is to put the result into another variable of type `double`, but your code is asking to store it into `total` which is of type `double[]` (array of `double`), and the compiler doesn't know how to resolve that.

You can either

1. Tell the compiler which element of `total` to store the result in,
   for example:

   ```
   total[0] = tuition + fee
   ```
2. Declare `total` as having the type of a single `double` instead of
   an array:

   ```
   double fee;
   double tuition;
   double total;
   double[] residence;

   // this is now okay
   total = tuition + fee;

   // this is again a type error because residence is still an array
   residence = total;
   ```

Comment: Although Java permits multiple variables in one declaration, declaring one at a time, as in this answer, makes it easier to find declarations as well as reducing the risk of the problem in the question.

Comment: I did this and it fixed my program. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For an array you must specify an index. Like:

```
total[0] = tuition + fee;
```

An array is a collection of something in this case doubles an array cannot equal one double it can have several double values at different indexes of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do this, correct me if I'm wrong

```
double tuition, residence, total;
```

The way you did it results in `residence` and `total` being arrays of double values, and not a double value like `tuition`.