# Java error: double cannot be converted to double[]

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling, compiler-errors, double

I am creating a method array and keep getting the error: double cannot be converted to double[].
Here is my code:

```
public static double[] calculate(double[] number1, double[] number2)
    {
        for( int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
          return number1[i] * (6.67e-3) / (number2[i]*number2[i])
        }
    }
```

I don't quite see why this is wrong because shouldn't the arrays have been converted to double by my for loop?

Comment: You aren't returning a double array... And the problem can't happen here, you aren't even working with booleans

Comment: This has been asked and answered numerous times on this and similar sites. Have you searched yet on the error message?

Comment: You want to create an array of double within the method, fill the array with double results, and then return it at the end.

Comment: @AndrewL.: since the parameters are arrays, and he uses a for loop, likely he wants to create a double array result, fill it, and return it.

Comment: yes I checked but the solutions they give are to create for loop which I did. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381737/after-i-compile-my-java-program-it-says-error-incompatible-types-double-canno

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hmm, you're right. I guess the OP wants to return the values in an array. To the OP, create a double array inside the method, populate it through the for loop, then return the array

Comment: Yes, and he's not doing that. His for loop is short-circuiting on its first iteration, trying to return a double value and not an array.

Answer (score 1):

Before suggesting the fix for compiler error, first need to understand the difference between primitive data type and array.

`double` is a [primitive data type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

An [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) is a container object which can contain data of same type.
**So double and double[] are not same.**

By seeing your code, it seems you want to return an array of double values computed out of input array values.

Here, you need to create an array `ret` of required size before assigning the values to individual elements of an array. Finally, return the array outside the loop.

```
 public static double[] calculate(double[] number1, double[] number2)
 {
        double[] ret = new double[10];
        for( int i=0; i<ret.length; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = number1[i] * (6.67e-3) / (number2[i]*number2[i]);
        }
        return  ret;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I see what I did... I thought that the required size would be automatic.